# Marginal effects in multinomial logit in R

Tags: r, multinomial-logit, marginal-effect

I am trying to calculate average marginal effects (dF/dx) for a multinomial logit model in R. Package mfx provides the solution only for binomial (and not the multinomial) model. Is there a package or sth to circumvent calculating it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Use margins package after multinom function in nnet package

```
install.packages("nnet")
install.packages("Zelig")
install.packages("margins")
library(nnet)
library(Zelig)
library(margins)
#use mexico data from Zelig package
data("mexico")
model <- multinom(vote88 ~ pristr + othcok + othsocok, mexico)
summary(model, cor = F)
marginal_effects(model)
cplot(model, "pristr")
library(pscl)
pR2(model)
```